# An Artistic Bunch

Tags: logical-deduction, no-computers, logic-grid

Luke, Clive, Anton and Paul are four talented creative artists, one a dancer, one a painter, one a singer, and one a writer. (Though not necessarily respectively.)

1. Luke and Anton were in the audience the night the singer made his debut on the concert stage.
2. Both Clive and the writer have sat for portraits by the painter.
3. The writer, whose biography of Paul was a best seller, is planning to write a biography of Luke.
4. Luke has never heard of Anton.

Who is the dancer? Who is the painter? Who is the singer? Who is the writer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Final occupations:

> Luke: **Dancer**
> Clive: **Singer**
> Anton: **Writer**
> Paul: **Painter**

---

#### Explanation:

Lets see what each line tells us

1:

> L and A are not the singer

2:

> C is not the painter nor the writer

3:

> L and P are not the writer

4:

> L and A have not interacted

---

So using this information lets see what everyone could be and narrow it down from there:

> L: Painter/Dancer
> A: Painter/Dancer/Writer
> C: Singer/Dancer
> P: Painter/Singer/Dancer

---

We can instantly see that

> A *must* be the writer, as he is the only possible person it could be.

This means that

> Luke cannot be the painter, or would have painted Anton and hence interacted with him breaking 4). L is therefore the Dancer.

So

> L is the dancer, A is the writer, C is therefore the singer and P is the painter.

Comment: Well done @Beastly Gerbil. Logical and precise.

Comment: @DrD maybe now, I originally missed that A had to be the occupation he was :P

Comment: Ah, yes. The "planning to" bit threw me off.